# Android-Socket doesn't send custom objects

Tags: android, sockets

I am trying to send a custom Object (`Info`) using a socket from a server to a client. Info class code is:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Info implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8967456786256719218L;


    private String ip;
    private int port;
    private List<String> responsibilityLines;


    public Info(String ip, int port, List<String> responsibilityLines) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
        this.responsibilityLines = responsibilityLines;
    }

    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }

    public void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    public int getSubscriberPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setSubscriberPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public List<String> getResponsibilityLines() {
        return responsibilityLines;
    }

    public void setResponsibilityLines(ArrayList<String> responsibilityLines) {
        this.responsibilityLines = responsibilityLines;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Info{" +
                "ip='" + ip + '\'' +
                ", port=" + port +
                ", responsibilityLines=" + responsibilityLines +
                '}';
    }
 }
```

The socket connection is established and any other java object or primitive type is sent successfully. However when I try to send a List of `Info` objects, the client blocks and wait to receive (which never happens). To send the object from the server I use:

```
 List<Info> infoList = new ArrayList<>();
 Info inf = new Info("192.168.78.45", 3456, null);
 infoList.add(inf);
 dos.writeObject(infoList);
 dos.flush();
```

and to receive the object I use:

```
List<Info> infoList;
infoList = (List<Info>) dis.readObject();
```

where dos is the `ObjectOutputStream` and dis is the `ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: Works for me. Perhaps some code you aren't showing is causing the problem. Please include the connection and stream setup code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ByteArrayOutputStream` as an inpute to `ObjectOutputStream()`

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)
oos.writeObject(infoList)
oos.close
```

given that your server knows who to parse info class.